# Magento 1.9. Cron job error Too late for the schedule

Tags: magento, cron, magento-1.7

I have configure my server(CPanel) to run cron.php file every */15 * * * *
my config.xml cron tab:

```
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <facebookreview>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>*/15 * * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>facebookreview/observer::email</model>
            </run>
        </facebookreview>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

The problem is in database in cron_schedule table i see my facebookreview task but it has an error

> exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Too late for the
>   schedule.' in /here_is_adress/app/Mage.php:595 Stack trace:...

**How to fix that 'Too late for the schedule' error ?**

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurred  when  run below logic

```
if ($time < $now - $scheduleLifetime)
```

when your `facebookreview sechule time < current time - cron schedule_lifetime`

Comment: Hi, thank you for answer. I see Magento use UTC time zone...but for all stores i have set my current time zone...how to set time zone without changing Mage.php or another core file ?

Comment: please check at cron_schehule atble

Comment: what i need to check there ?

Comment: Hi Amit, We have checked all my cron working proper but third-pary extension every cron missed with below errors.


Mage_Core_Exception: Too late for the schedule. in /home/XXXX/public_html/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /home/XXXX/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(294): Mage::throwException('Too late for th...')
#1 /home/XXXX/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(72): 

any Solution ?